# Where are power series uniformly continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, power-series, continuity, uniform-continuity

As far as I know, $f(x)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty a_n(x-x_0)^n$ is continuous on the whole convergence interval $K:=\{x\in\mathbb R:|x-x_0|<r\}$. Is there anything we could say about uniform continuity?

*Added*: Would it be correct to claim the following?

> Power series is uniformly continuous on $\bar K:=\{x\in\mathbb R:|x-x_0|<\bar r\}$ where $0<\bar r<r$.

I'm asking for the clarification since we haven't defined compactness yet.

Comment: Yes, the series converges uniformly on compact subsets of $K$.

Comment: And is likewise uniformly continuous on compact subsets of $K$.

Comment: @CameronBuie: Must have been asleep. My comment is irrelevant.

Comment: It converges normally, hence uniformly, on every compact subset of the interval of convergence. And likewise on compact subsets of the disk of convergence in $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: @julien: So it could be written as "Power series is uniformly continuous on $\bar K:=\{x\in\mathbb R:|x-x_0|<\bar r\}$ where $0<\bar r<r$." Correct?

Comment: @mathusiast What you say is correct. It would be slightly more natural to let $\leq \overline{r}$ in the definition of your disk where $f$ is uniformly continuous. Not then that it is nothing but the usual [Heine-Cantor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heine%E2%80%93Cantor_theorem): $f$ continuous is uniformly continuous on compact subsets.

Answer (score -1):

Check relevant theorems- Weierstrass M-test can be used to prove the uniform continuity.

Comment: The set $K$ is not compact. The open cover $\{ B(x_0,r-\frac{1}{n}) \}_n$ has no finite subcover.